# Pagination is not working using criteria jpa typedquery throwing error

Tags: jpa, criteria

I am trying to achieve pagination, below is the code

```
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();           
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();           
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);            
    Root<Employee> from= criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(from.get("STATUS"), "Fair"));  
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> select = criteriaQuery.select(from);

    TypedQuery<Employee> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select)
            .setFirstResult(0)
        .setMaxResults(5);
```

i am getting the below error while trying to execute:-
SQL Error: 923, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: could you turn on the sql output and include the generated sql that you are trying to execute?

Comment: select TOP(?) employee0_.STATUS as STATUS _1_ from EMPLOYEE employee0_;  , i am using oracle database , which uses rownum, i am not sure what's going on. i.e

Comment: Is  typedQuery .setFirstResult(0) and typedQuery  .setMaxResults(5) not supported by oracle database? i need to achieve:-                 SELECT rs.* from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.APPROVEDTIME desc) as row_num  from Employee t ) rs where rs.row_num >= 1 
and rs.row_num  < 10  order by rs.row_num

Comment: top(?) is not part of Oracle, as far as I know.  are you sure you set the dialect correctly?